# How I assign a value to variable from constructor in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

Problem with my Angular app. This is my first angular web. I want to assign a value to my variable named `_name` from the constructor. I tried the below way but didn't work. How can I assign a value for that?
The value comes to that page in the `console.log` the value is displayed. I want to assign that value to my `_name` variable and display the value in the HTML page when the page load. How can I do that ?

This is my current code

```typescript
export class DashboardTemplateComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private userSub: Subscription;
    inAuthenticate = false;
     _name: any;
      constructor(private router: Router, private authService: userService ) {
        this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
          console.log(user.token);
          return this._name = user.name;
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
          this.inAuthenticate = !user ? false : true;
    
        return this._name = user.name;
        });
      }
```

[image: code screen shot]

Comment: remove `return` keyword

Comment: I removed but still not working

Comment: what are you getting? and no need to call service twice(constructor and init)

Comment: Ya, I modify my code as follows . But I get a null value in html page. in console deisplayed the value.   export class DashboardTemplateComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private userSub: Subscription;
    inAuthenticate = false;
     _name: any;
      constructor(private router: Router, private authService: userService ) {
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
          this.inAuthenticate = !user ? false : true;
         this._name = user.name;
        });
      }}

Comment: what did you get in subscription block `console.log(user)`

Comment: console.log(user.name);   I got the user's name

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code like below avoiding complication

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


  export class DashboardTemplateComponent implements OnInit {
    destroyed$ = new Subject();
    inAuthenticate = false;
    _name: any;
    name$ = this.authService.user.pipe(
        tap(user => this._name = user.name),
        tap(user => this.inAuthenticate = !user ? false : true)
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      )
     
      constructor(private router: Router, private authService: userService ) {
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.name$.subscribe();
      }
  }
```

Comment: 1) you meant to subscribe to `name$`, 2) you should add the `OnDestroy` logic completely if you start implemeenting it. (And you don't need multiple taps, just add `{}`).